# Getting Logs from Google App Engine Application deployed on Google app-spot from Ubuntu

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, ubuntu, terminal

How can I get the logs for my application deployed on Google app-spot through Ubuntu Terminal. I have tried the command in the shell script:

$./appcfg.sh request_logs mylogs.txt

but it says that bad-arguments. The application ID for my application deployed on app-spot is 'vikastest111'.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

where is appcfg.sh coming from ? 
Its not part of the google_appengine distribution.

The standard usage for appcfg.py is 
`Usage: appcfg.py [options] request_logs <directory> <output_file>`

where directory is where you app.yaml is located .

To get specific help for a command do

`python ~/google_appengine/appcfg.py request_logs --help`

Comment: But the SDK distribution is for Java and there we are having the command ./appcfg.sh to run the script to get the logs detail.

Comment: So the problem still exists as to how can I get the details of the all the types of complete logs such as info, severe and warning from the deployed application

Comment: You didn't mention java in your original question,

Comment: Have you read the java docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Logs. The arguments are the same when you use java. You haven.t included one of the required arguments

Comment: Yes that argument is actually the path to the war. But I am not getting as to what argument I should pass for this.

Comment: Where is your war file in relation to the working directory where run run appcfg.sh.  You should be able to work it out from that.

Comment: I had read the java docs in the link provided. But the problem is the same, for one of the option myapps/war, what exactly should be written for this option as my application is not local to the SDK it is deployed to google app-spot.

Comment: The code has been deployed to google app engine app-spot and we can access the application through http://vikastest111.appspot.com. But currently the app will not work as I have reverted back my changes but the account is still there for application and I can view the logs from the admin login of the application. Now I want the logs on my personal computer so that I can do the necessary analysis based on the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$./appcfg.sh request_logs /path/to/your/appengine/project mylogs.txt
```

Comment: I have tried the following commands, but it says bad arguments for all of the command  (i) $./appcfg.sh request_logs vikastest111 mylogs.txt (ii) $./appcfg.sh request_logs vikastest111/war mylogs.txt (iii) $./appcfg.sh request_logs http://vikastest111.appspot.com mylogs.txt (iv) $./appcfg.sh request_logs http://vikastest111.appspot.com/war mylogs.txt. Please advice.